# Is it possible to call cucumber step from ruby method?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

It's possible to [call cucumber step from step definition](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions). I'd want to call step from ordinary ruby method, i.e.:

```
module MyHelpers
  def self.my_method
    step %{My step}
  end
end
```

Currently when I do it, I have

```
undefined method `step' for MyHelpers:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Is it possible to invoke step from Ruby method?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can call step on ruby methods.
Since "step" is for repeating for step definition on cucumber using capybara gem.

Better way to call your method again without repeating just define it as global method and call it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call one step definition from another step definition do this:

And(/^I delete the integration quote$/) do
  step "I delete the quote"
end

And(/^I delete the quote$/) do
end

Important to remember is the "And", "When" and "Then" is inherited, i.e I cannot do this

Then(/^I delete the integration quote$/) do
  step "And I delete the quote"
end

Comment: The question is about calling it from ordinary ruby code, not step definition.

Comment: Are you not calling it in context of a step definition? That is a step definition calls method A which calls method B which then calls your step? I don't see why you would call a step outside the context of a step.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to call stepdef using `step` from method A or B.

Comment: It is very possible, we do it all the time in our project.